# ReferenceError: response is not defined on autocomplete jquery ajax call in singleton design pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete in my solution but I got an error ***ReferenceError: response is not defined***

Here is my code

```js
(function ($) {
        $.SupportArticleObj = function (p) {
            var SupportArticle = {
                config: {
                    isPostBack: false,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { data: '' },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    baseURL: "Modules/SupportArticle/Services/SupportArticleWebService.asmx/",
                    url: "",
                    method: "",
                    ajaxCallMode: 0,
                    PortalID: PortalID,
                    UserModuleID: UserModuleID,
                    SecureToken: SecureToken,
                    UserName: UserName
    
                },
                init: function () {
                    $("#searchSupport").autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            searchTerm = request.term;
                            SupportArticle.getSearchData(searchTerm);
                        }
                    });
                },
                getSearchData: function (searchTearm) {
                    SupportArticle.config.method = "SearchSupportArticle";
                    SupportArticle.config.url = SupportArticle.config.baseURL + SupportArticle.config.method;
                    SupportArticle.config.data = JSON2.stringify({
                        searchTerm: searchTerm,
                        portalID: SupportArticle.config.PortalID,
                        userModuleID: SupportArticle.config.UserModuleID,
                        userName: SupportArticle.config.UserName,
                        secureToken: SupportArticle.config.SecureToken
                    });
                    SupportArticle.ajaxCall(SupportArticle.config);
                },
                ajaxSuccess: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                },
                ajaxFailure: function () {
                    jAlert('Somethings went wrong', 'Support Article');
                },
                ajaxCall: function (config) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: SupportArticle.config.type,
                        contentType: SupportArticle.config.contentType,
                        cache: SupportArticle.config.cache,
                        url: SupportArticle.config.url,
                        data: SupportArticle.config.data,
                        dataType: SupportArticle.config.dataType,
                        success: SupportArticle.ajaxSuccess,
                        error: SupportArticle.ajaxFailure,
                        async: SupportArticle.config.async
                    });
                }
            };
            SupportArticle.init();
        };
        $.fn.callSupportArticle = function (p) {
            $.SupportArticleObj(p);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

What I am trying to do here is, I am calling a webservice which will search the records on database and return as a list and I want to bind that list on textbox as a autocomplete. But the problem is while running the solution in browser I got an error ReferenceError: response is not defined.

I was trying http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/da55bf/Asp-Net-autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-json-and-ajax/ as reference.

How can I solve the issue of ***ReferenceError: response is not defined***

[image: While running on browser error seems like this. ReferenceError: response is not defined]

Comment: could u add a link to the source of the library in use?

Comment: its jQuery UI - v1.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your script like below:

```
AutoDemoDataBase: function () {
            $("#lytA_ctl29_txtSearchName").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = JSON.stringify({
                        userModuleID: UserModuleID,
                        portalID: autoComplete.config.portalId,
                        prefix: $("#lytA_ctl29_txtSearchName").val(),
                        userName: autoComplete.config.UserName,
                        secureToken: SageFrameSecureToken
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: autoComplete.config.type,
                        contentType: autoComplete.config.contentType,
                        cache: autoComplete.config.cache,
                        url: autoComplete.config.baseURL + "GetNames",
                        data: param,
                        dataType: autoComplete.config.dataType,
                        async: autoComplete.config.async,
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                               return {                                       
                                    value: item.Name
                                }
                            }))
                           },
                        error: function (response) {
                            jAlert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            jAlert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#hfId").val(i.item.val);
                    $('#test').text(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        }
```

Your ajax success function is out of response scope.

Comment: I need to follow singleton pattern

Comment: I have updated my answer use like above in your singleton pattern